# Routing issue home network 2 gateways

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have setup a RPi as a VPN Gateteway,
I have change some devices' (1 PC + 1 NAS) default gateway to point to RPI IP@
So far everything works fine.

I have setup port forwarding in my internet router to be able to reach my NAS from internet. And it used to work before I installed the RPI.

Pb is, when I try to connect to my NAS from an internet IP.... no response.

The issue comes from my routing rules I guess, but I'm noob at linux/rounting/RPI.

I am using only wired network connections to my Raspberry Pi.

This is my systemd dhcpcd status:

```
$sudo systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-12-04 17:27:32 UTC; 22h ago
  Process: 333 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -w (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 564 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           ├─474 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
           └─564 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w

Dec 04 17:27:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.24
Dec 04 17:27:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: probing address 192.168.1.24/24
Dec 04 17:27:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Dec 04 17:27:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: leased 192.168.1.24 for 43200 seconds
Dec 04 17:27:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Dec 04 17:27:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.1.254
Dec 04 17:27:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: /sbin/resolvconf: 230: /lib/resolvconf/libc: cannot create /etc/resolv.conf: Operation not permitted
Dec 04 17:27:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: Too few arguments.
Dec 04 17:27:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: eth0: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Dec 04 17:27:39 raspberrypi dhcpcd[564]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
Warning: dhcpcd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

This is my routing table:

```
$route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface 
0.0.0.0         172.21.22.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
81.171.107.18   192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       172.21.22.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.21.22.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

Please help. Thank you

---

**1st:** Wired Connection

**2nd:**
[image: dhcpd output]

**3rd:**
[image]

Hi, 
Here is what I get:

$ lsattr /etc/resolv.conf

----i---------e---- /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: I think you'll need to show us exactly the rules that you're using...

Comment: **1st:** Are the RPi network connections wired or wireless? ... **2nd** On the RPi what is the output of `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd` ... **3rd** On the RPi what is the output of `sudo route` ... Please update the question with the outputs.

Comment: 1st: The RPI connection is wired

Comment: 2nd:
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-12-04 17:27:32 UTC; 22h ago
  Process: 333 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -w (code=exited, status=0/SU
 Main PID: 564 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           ├─474 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iw
           └─564 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w

Comment: Dec 04 17:27:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.24
Dec 04 17:27:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: probing address 192.168.1.24/24
Dec 04 17:27:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Dec 04 17:27:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: leased 192.168.1.24 for 43200 sec
Dec 04 17:27:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Dec 04 17:27:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.

Comment: Dec 04 17:27:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: /sbin/resolvconf: 230: /lib/resolvconf/
Dec 04 17:27:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[333]: Too few arguments.
Dec 04 17:27:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Dec 04 17:27:39 raspberrypi dhcpcd[564]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
Warning: dhcpcd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload
lines 1-22/22 (END)

Comment: 3rd:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.21.22.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
81.171.107.18   192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       172.21.22.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.21.22.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0

Comment: It seems there are some problems with the resolv.conf file attributes... what is the output of `lsattr /etc/resolv.conf` ... This time **Please edit the question.  Do not place new information in the comments.**

Comment: Did you get to a solution by now?

Answer (score 0):

Your pi has 2 default routes:
0.0.0.0 (= default gw) with metric 0 (highest priority) to the `tun0` interface.
default with metric (202) to `eth0` interface.

Since the default gateway to `tun0` has the highest priority, your pi will route every (unknown) route to `tun0`.

I can't make up your complete setup from your post, but I think this might be your issue.